# Not throwing custom exception in case of transaction management

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, transactions

When I am giving `amt > sabal` and expecting that else branch should execute (which throws custom exception) but it does not executing corresponding catch.

Where is the logical error in this program? Whether it is happening because setAutoCommit remains false or some other logical error?

Class Account:

```
package com.jlcindia.transactionmanagement;

import java.sql.*;

public class Account {

int dabal,sabal,amt;

public void transfer(int sa,int da,int bal){

    amt=bal;
    Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jlcstudents","root","garima");
        st=con.createStatement();

        rs=st.executeQuery(String.format("select bal from account where acc_no=%d",da));
        if(rs.next())
            dabal=rs.getInt(1);
        else
            throw new InvalidAccountNumber(da);

        rs=st.executeQuery(String.format("select bal from account where acc_no=%d", sa));
        if(rs.next())
            sabal=rs.getInt(1);
        else 
            throw new InvalidAccountNumber(da);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    try{
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        if(amt<=sabal){
        String qry=String.format("update account set bal=%d+%d where acc_no=%d", dabal,bal,da);
        st.executeUpdate(qry);

        String qry1=String.format("update account set bal=%d-%d where acc_no=%d", sabal,bal,sa);
        st.executeUpdate(qry1);

        con.commit();
        System.out.println("Transaction successfull");

        }
        else 
            throw new InsufficientFundException();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        try{
        con.rollback();
        System.out.println("Transaction rollbacked");
        }
        catch(SQLException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    finally{
        try{
        if(st!=null)
            st.close();
        if(con!=null)
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Class Lab25:

```
package com.jlcindia.transactionmanagement;

public class Lab25 {
     public static void main(String[] args){
       Account acc=new Account();
       acc.transfer(1, 2, 10000);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out to give braces around the if else statement.
May be it will help

```
if(condition){
statements.....
}
else{
statements....
}
```

second solution is 
You have to every time create a new statement object rather than using the previous one.
when work of one object is finished close it by calling

```
statementObject.close();
```

Comment: create a new object everytime will be time consuming...Is there any other way to solve this so that when condition in if(amt<=sabal) fails corresponding else executes?